# How can I configure an Epsom XP-300 printer on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have just bought an Epson XP-300 laser printer and I can't get it to work properly on Ubuntu. I'm a complete novice when it comes to Ubuntu and Linux, so I basically went to "Printers" and tried configuring it that way but my printer model doesn't even appear on the list.

When I try using the "generic" configuration it either doesn't print or just prints out gibberish.

This is REALLY frustrating. What can I do to get this printer to work properly under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the drivers. I had to jump through hoops to get my XP-400 to work properly, but I did not have these drivers at the time.

[Download Printer Driver  ESC/P Driver (full feature)](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=17706&DSCCHK=9c8abc176ede6865044814d83da38de3a4e486ad)

[Download Printer Driver  ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=19825&DSCCHK=5c7b4ff541de9a525dc84fb439258ab38e7fefd2)

[Download Scanner Driver  core package&data package](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=21580&DSCCHK=ea245da3525f56d8ca2ab9408ed2d6d8b481d435)

If these links fail, just go to [Download drivers and Software](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) and search for XP-300.

If there are still issues, there is a good FAQ here to help you start debugging.
[database/cupsfaq](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/databasecupsfaq)